# Count down with x ms intervals

Tags: javascript

I want my loop to count down every 200ms.

```
let myArr = [3, 4, 5, 6];

for (let i = myArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(myArr[i]); // execute this console.log every 200ms. (not 200 MS after the last one.)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes much more sense to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) for this than any for-loop, as `setInterval` was designed to execute code every `x` milliseconds:

```js
let myArr = [3, 4, 5, 6];
var i = myArr.length - 1;

let interval = window.setInterval(() => {
  if (i >= 0) {
    console.log(myArr[i]);
    i--;
  } else {
    window.clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 200);
```